# eclipse how to print only selected string from scanned file

Tags: java, eclipse, class, printing, console

I'm trying to done some homeworks, and I need some help. I have a code which reads files with data, and asking to select a match with type in a number. When user types, console write You have selected: - and here I need to write selected match string from scanned file. Maybe some one can help me what I should do to print this ? My code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class teller {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String[] rungtyniuBilietai = {"1) Namų rungtynės","2) Išvykos rungtynės"};
    static String[] arNorite = {"1) Taip","2) Ne"};
    static File dataNamai = new File("src/dataNamai.txt");
    static File dataIsvyka = new File("src/dataIsvyka.txt");



    static String name;
    static int number;
    static int number2;

    public static void getName() throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Prašome įvesti savo vardą:");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Sveiki, - "+name+", Klaipėdos 'Neptūno' fane!");
        getTicket();
    }

    public static void getTicket() throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Prašome pasirinkti skaičių rungtynių , į kurias norite įsigyti bilietus:");
        for(int i=0;i < rungtyniuBilietai.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(rungtyniuBilietai[i]);
        }
        number = scan.nextInt();
        if (number == 1) {
            dataNamai();
            }else{
                dataIsvyka();
            }
        number2=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Jūs pasirinkote bilietus į: ");
        getSeats();
    }

    public static void dataNamai() throws FileNotFoundException {
            int b;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(dataNamai);
            scan.useDelimiter("\n |, |;");      
            // iterate through the file line by line
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Prašome pasirinkti rungtynių bilietus:");
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                for(b=1;scan.hasNextLine();b++) {
                // print the contents of a file by line
                System.out.println(+b+". Neptunas - "+scan.nextLine());
                }
            }
            // close the scanner object;
            scan.close();
        }

    public static void dataIsvyka() throws FileNotFoundException {
        int b;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(dataIsvyka);
        scan.useDelimiter("\n |, |;"); 
        // iterate through the file line by line
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Prašome pasirinkti rungtynių bilietus:");
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            for(b=1;scan.hasNextLine();b++) {
            // print the contents of a file by line
            System.out.println(+b+". Neptunas - "+scan.nextLine());
            }
        }
        // close the scanner object;
        scan.close();
    }

    public static void getSeats() throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Kiek vietų norėtumėte rezervuoti?");
        String seats = scan.next();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Jūsų rezervuotų vietų skaičius: "+seats+" į rungtynes: "+rungtyniuBilietai[number-1].substring(3, rungtyniuBilietai[number-1].length()));
        System.out.println("Ar norite rezervuoti daugiau?");
        for(int i=0;i < arNorite.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(arNorite[i]);
        }
        number = scan.nextInt();
        if (number == 1) {
            getTicket();
            }else{
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Ačiū, kad naudojates mūsų paslaugomis!");
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        getName();
    }
}
```

And here is what my console shows:

```
Prašome įvesti savo vardą:
as

Sveiki, - as, Klaipėdos 'Neptūno' fane!

Prašome pasirinkti skaičių rungtynių , į kurias norite įsigyti bilietus:
1) Namų rungtynės
2) Išvykos rungtynės
1

Prašome pasirinkti rungtynių bilietus:
1. Neptunas - Žalgiris, 17:45 val., Data: 2018-01-01;
2. Neptunas - Lietuvos Rytas, 18:45 val., Data: 2018-01-04;
3. Neptunas - Šiauliai, 18:00 val., Data: 2018-02-01;
4. Neptunas - Lietkabelis, 18:00 val., Data: 2018-02-05;
5. Neptunas - Nevėžis, 19:00 val., Data: 2018-03-17;
6. Neptunas - Pieno žvaigždės, 18:20 val., Data: 2018-03-30;
7. Neptunas - Vytautas, 19:10 val., Data: 2018-04-19;
8. Neptunas - Dzūkija, 17:45 val., Data: 2018-04-26;
9. Neptunas - Elan, 18:20 val., Data: 2018-04-29;
10. Neptunas - Ventspils, 19:00 val., Data: 2018-05-02;
11. Neptunas - Gaziantep, 19:30 val., Data: 2018-05-06;
12. Neptunas - PAOK, 19:05 val., Data: 2018-05-11;
13. Neptunas - MHP Riesen, 18:00 val., Data: 2018-05-14;
14. Neptunas - SikeliArchivi, 18:25 val., Data: 2018-05-17;
15. Neptunas - Iberostar, 18:45 val., Data: 2018-05-20;
16. Neptunas - Juventus, 19:20 val., Data: 2018-05-23;
17. Neptunas - SIG, 19:15 val., Data: 2018-05-26;
18. Neptunas - Aris, 19:20 val., Data: 2018-05-30;
19. Neptunas - AS Monaco, 19:45 val., Data: 2018-06-03;
20. Neptunas - Banvit, 20:00 val., Data: 2018-06-10;
21. Neptunas - Besiktas, 18:00 val., Data: 2018-06-13;
22. Neptunas - CEZ, 18:00 val., Data: 2018-06-16;
23. Neptunas - Dinamo, 18:10 val., Data: 2018-06-20;
24. Neptunas - Elan Chalon, 18:30 val., Data: 2018-06-24;
25. Neptunas - Enisey, 17:50 val., Data: 2018-06-27;
26. Neptunas - EWE Baskets, 17:30 val., Data: 2018-06-31;
27. Neptunas - Iberostar, 17:30 val., Data: 2018-07-03;
28. Neptunas - Bayreuth, 17:55 val., Data: 2018-07-06;
29. Neptunas - Movistar, 18:55 val., Data: 2018-07-09;
30. Neptunas - Nanterre, 19:55 val., Data: 2018-07-12;
31. Neptunas - Oostende, 19:05 val., Data: 2018-07-15;
32. Neptunas - Olimpija, 17:50 val., Data: 2018-07-18;
33. Neptunas - Karsiyaka, 18:05 val., Data: 2018-07-21;
34. Neptunas - Rosa, 18:30 val., Data: 2018-07-23;
35. Neptunas - Sidigas, 19:45 val., Data: 2018-07-26;
36. Neptunas - Stelmet, 20:45 val., Data: 2018-07-28;
37. Neptunas - Telekom, 21:05 val., Data: 2018-07-30;
38. Neptunas - UCAM, 18:05 val., Data: 2018-08-03;
39. Neptunas - Umana, 18:40 val., Data: 2018-08-05;
40. Neptunas - UNET, 20:35 val., Data: 2018-08-07;
41. Neptunas - Holon, 19:55 val., Data: 2018-08-09;
42. Neptunas - Avellino, 18:35 val., Data: 2018-08-12;
43. Neptunas - Estudiantes, 18:15 val., Data: 2018-08-15;
44. Neptunas - Nymburk, 17:40 val., Data: 2018-08-18;
45. Neptunas - Sassari, 18:10 val., Data: 2018-08-21;
46. Neptunas - Barcelona, 19:15 val., Data: 2018-08-24;
47. Neptunas - Bayern, 20:00 val., Data: 2018-08-27;
48. Neptunas - Panathinaikos, 18:40 val., Data: 2018-08-30;
49. Neptunas - Aris, 19:00 val., Data: 2018-09-03;
50. Neptunas - Olympiacos, 19:35 val., Data: 2018-09-05;
35

Jūs pasirinkote bilietus į: 
Kiek vietų norėtumėte rezervuoti?
1
```

Comment: You could translate your code and leave the unnecessary parts out to make it more readable.

Comment: Please check how to create a [mcve]